# window.location.href.match Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {

    var pathname = (window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]);

    $('#menu dl dd a#toparrow').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('href') == pathname) {
            $(this).addClass('currenttop');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a link to my website:  http://bluraymoviestore.com

The purpose of the script is to make the arrow image stay on the current page, like it does when you first click to the categories.

The script works when I'm clicked on the parent page, but when I click to the next page under the same category, the script no longer works (example: works with `/bluraynewreleases` but not `/bluraynewreleases-2625374011-rc-2-new_releases.html`).  What do I need to add to the code to make it work?

Comment: Open the console, and you'll see : `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null `, on line 48, referring to the last `[0]` in your code as match does'nt return an array for that URL, as it does'nt match ?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't match anything so it throws an error when you attempt to access `[0]` on it. Assuming your regex is correct this should fix the issue.

```
$(function(){
    var matches = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/);
    if (matches && matches.length) {
        var pathname = (matches[0]);

        $('#menu dl dd a#toparrow').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('href') == pathname) {
                $(this).addClass('currenttop');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work.  How do I fix my regex?  I'm a total newbie to JavaScript.

Comment: You were getting a missing } error, I modified the above, give that a go.

Comment: @BillyW: Are you new to regex, too? Your expression will fail to match if the input string ends in a `/`. What did you *intend* it to do?

Comment: Yes, new to regex as well.  I'm new to anything that has to do with programming/scripting with the exception of very limited PHP knowledge.  My goal is to keep the blue arrow on the menu when the user is under that parent category.